# What's the maximum number of steps in a non-loopy maze?

Tags: graph-theory

I've written an maze-solving algorithm in 2D (with a robot) that does the following:

At first, the robot will explore (keep going down one path, avoiding walls). When it encounters a junction that it's already come across before, if reverses direction and backtracks.

If the robot encounters a junction with an unexplored exit while backtracking, it randomly chooses one of these exits and explores down it.

If the robot encounters a junction with no unexplored exits while backtracking it backtracks in the direction from which it came when it first reached the junction.

**Given this, is there a (least upper bound) for the maximum number of steps the robot will take to navigate the maze?**

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/85141/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2556885/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

If the distance between junctions is always 1 (if necessary, introduce "dummy" 2-way junctions 1 unit apart along longer passageways) then the maximum distance that the robot travels to solve the maze is $2n-1$ where $n$ is the number of junctions.

We can see this is an upper bound on the maximum because the robot does not travel along any passage more than twice, and it only travels along the final passage (with the goal/exit at the end) once.

And this upper bound is actually attained if we have a maze where there the goal is 1 unit away from the junction at the entrance, but there are other branches from this junction, and the robot chooses and fully explores each of these other branches before it chooses the exit branch.

Answer (score 0):

The best upper bound is around $2n,$ where $n$ is the number of junctions. Essentially, one could search the 'wrong' part of the array and have to backtrack complete. Think of the path graph with vertices $1,2,\dots,n,$ where the exit is at 1, and you start at 2 and start searching $3,4,\dots.$

If you want a more precise number, such as $2n-3,$ you'll need to give a slightly more formal description of the problem.